# C++ Vector Size is Zero

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to create a function that renders everything in a vector of displayobject objects (on another thread). I am using SDL thread.

Here is the displayobject.h:

```
class DisplayObject
{
protected:
    int width;
    int height;
    int x;
    int y;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;

public:
    ~DisplayObject();
    int getX();
    void setX(int x);
    int getY();
    void setY(int y);
    int getWidth();
    void setWidth(int width);
    int getHeight();
    void setHeight(int height);
    SDL_Texture* getTexture();
    SDL_Renderer* getRenderer();
};
```

In graphics.h I have these variables:

```
std::vector<DisplayObject> imgArr;
SDL_Thread* renderThread;
static int renderLoop(void* vectorPointer);
```

This code is in the graphics constructor:

```
TextLabel textLabel(graphics->getRenderer(), 300, 80, "Hallo Welt", 50,       Color(255, 0, 255), "Xenotron.ttf");
//TextLabel inherits from DisplayObject
imgArr.push_back(textLabel);
renderThread = SDL_CreateThread(Graphics::renderLoop, "renderLoop", &imgArr);
```

This is the render loop function:

```
int Graphics::renderLoop(void* param)
{
    int counter = 0;
    bool rendering = true;
    std::vector<DisplayObject>* imgArr = (std::vector<DisplayObject>*)param;

    while (rendering)
    {
        cout << imgArr->size() << endl;

        counter++;
        if (counter > 600)
        {
            rendering = false;
        }

        SDL_Delay(16);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it only prints 0's in the console. Why does it do that? It is supposed to write 1 since I pushed on object into it.

Comment: On an unrelated point, just because a function wants a pointer argument doesn't mean the variable you pass have to be a pointer. Instead use the address-of operator `&` to make a pointer to the variable when needed.

Comment: `new std::vector` is usually wrong. Why not just `std::vector<DisplayObject> imgArr;`?

Comment: I'm going to guess that `imgArr` is going out of scope and is destructed. But it's impossible to tell without a complete compilable example.

Comment: Either work with the debugger, or add print statements (the pointer 'this' and hello/world) into the DisplayObject class. Also note, that a vector of <base> will peal off the derived part. You will store displayobjects, not TextLabels in the vector. To fix that you could instead store unique_ptr<DisplayObject> or DisplayObject* in the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you insert a `TextLabel` into `std::vector<DisplayObject>`, what is stored in the vector is not your original `TextLabel` object, but a `DisplayObject` copy-constructed from the `TextLabel`. What you want to do is create your `TextLabel`s with `new`, store pointers to them, and call `delete` when you no longer need them.

The best solution would be to use `boost::ptr_vector<DisplayObject>` instead - it will automatically call `delete` when you erase objects from it.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html

If you can't use Boost, but can use C++11, you can use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DisplayObject>>`.